# How to process output of the matchShapes() function

Tags: c++, opencv, shapes

Given below is the code of the program used to compare 2 shapes.

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    RNG rng(12345);
    Mat image1=cvLoadImage("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/circle1.png",1);
    Mat image2=cvLoadImage("C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/circle2.png",1);
    Mat imagegray1, imagegray2, imageresult1, imageresult2;
    int thresh=150;
    double ans=0, result=0;;
    cvtColor(image1, imagegray1,CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvtColor(image2,imagegray2,CV_BGR2GRAY);

    vector<vector<Point>>contours1, contours2;
    vector<Vec4i>hierarchy1, hierarchy2;

    Canny(imagegray1, imageresult1,thresh, thresh*2);
    Canny(imagegray2, imageresult2,thresh, thresh*2);

    findContours(imageresult1,contours1,hierarchy1,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));
    for(int i=0;i<contours1.size();i++)
    {
        Scalar color=Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255));
        drawContours(imageresult1,contours1,i,color,1,8,hierarchy1,0,Point());
    }

    findContours(imageresult2,contours2,hierarchy2,CV_RETR_TREE,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE,cvPoint(0,0));
    for(int i=0;i<contours2.size();i++)
    {
        Scalar color=Scalar(rng.uniform(0, 255), rng.uniform(0,255), rng.uniform(0,255));
        drawContours(imageresult2,contours2,i,color,1,8,hierarchy2,0,Point());
    }
    for(int i=0;i<contours1.size();i++)
    {
        ans=matchShapes(contours1[i],contours2[i],CV_CONTOURS_MATCH_I1,0);
        cout<<ans;
        getchar();
    }
}
```

I am running it with these images:

[image: Image 1]
[image]

The result in this case i.e. the value of the variable ans is:

> 8.97971e-007
>
> 1.73019e-005
>
> 2.25315e-006
>
> 2.21416e-005

How to use these values to determine if the shapes match each other?

Comment: Did you find the answer for this or not, I also have the same questoin. Thank you!

Comment: @BahramdunAdil Gimme like tonight? I'll get back to you with the updates on this ASAP.

Comment: OK. Thank you! I am waiting

Comment: Did you find the answer for this or not, I also want the same thing with matchShapes(); Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/prakharmohan0809/OpenCV-Track-Circle

Comment: No, it works with circles only, I want to match known shapes with contour, maybe different shapes not only circle with using  matchShapes() function, the only with this function that I have is I cannot process the out put of the function, I cannot get the percentage of the result. If you have any example share with me. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I found [this](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_contours/py_contours_more_functions/py_contours_more_functions.html#match-shapes) which shows results. He gets 0,00 when matching two identical contours and 0,001 with a rotated contour. I would say that there's no match above 0,1 depending on preferred precision. I couldn't find anything explaining the returned value other than this.

```
8,97971e-7 = 0,000000897971
1,73019e-5 = 0,0000173019
2,25315e-6 = 0,00000225315
2,21416e-5 = 0,0000221416
```

Your results shows that all the found contours are really good matches. Try `drawContours` to see what contours are actually found and then the results may become understandable. Maybe you could also apply `approxPolyDP` and see if you'll get better results.